# How To get Sender E-mail from Device?

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, email

I am sending some data from my application to server. my data consist of different fields as my code shown below

```
-(void)createXML
{
xmlStr = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>\n<jand_req>\n<inquiryList>\n<productArr>\n";
NSString *nameStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<name>%@</name>\n",name.text];
xmlStr=[xmlStr stringByAppendingString:nameStr];
NSString *compNameStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<comp_name>%@</comp_name>\n",compName.text];
xmlStr=[xmlStr stringByAppendingString:compNameStr];
NSString *cityStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<city>%@</city>\n",city.text];
xmlStr=[xmlStr stringByAppendingString:cityStr];
NSString *countryStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<country>%@</country>\n",[nameToCode objectForKey:country.text]];
xmlStr=[xmlStr stringByAppendingString:countryStr];
NSString *commentsStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<comment>%@</comment>\n",commentsBox.text];
xmlStr=[xmlStr stringByAppendingString:commentsStr];
xmlStr=[xmlStr stringByAppendingString:@"</userDetail>\n</inquiryList>\n</jand_req>"];
}
```

After this i send the above data to server as my code shown below

```
- (void)submitForm
 {
[self createXML];

NSLog(@"myaccesscode%@",[fn getValFromSettings:@"accessCode"]);
   NSString *serviceUrlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/API_sendmail.php?access_code=%@",domainName,apiFolderPath,[fn getValFromSettings:@"accessCode"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",serviceUrlStr);
    NSURL * serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[serviceUrlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSMutableURLRequest * serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:100];
    [serviceRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPBody:[xmlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *conn=[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:serviceRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES] autorelease];
}
```

All the above code works fine for me but now i want to include an another feature in this code Which consist of sender E-mail address but this sender E-mail must be fetch from device same as when we use MFMailComposeViewController in application then automatically it gets sender E-mail Address from Device.Any help will be appriated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

NSString *emailAddr = @"";
ABPerson *aPerson = [[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] me];
ABMultiValue *emails = [aPerson valueForProperty:kABEmailProperty];
if([emails count] > 0)
    emailAddr = [emails valueAtIndex:0];
```

don't forget to add AddressBook.framework.

Now, the emailAddr contains the senders email which you can append to your xml string or wherever you want it to!

```
-(void)createXML
{
    // Your code
    NSString *emailStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<email>%@</email>\n",emailAddr];
    xmlStr=[xmlStr stringByAppendingString:emailStr];
}
```

happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for quick response but how we can add this in xmlStr when we sending data to server.

Comment: @NSCool you can use the emailAddr wherever you want to use it! please see my updated answer to have a look!

Comment: oky it looks good only last thing tell me using this code if any reply comes from server then where it goes?i want that reply must come to sender E-mail address.

Comment: on Server you should parse the email tag and send the email to that address and the reply would come to sender's email address!

Comment: Thanks a lot still client not give me server access so for the time being i am unable to check it from server side...by the way your code looks oky.so i will check it in later part of the day as client give me server access.if i feel any problem then sure i will contact you.

Comment: i am using xcode 4.5 with ios6 so its accept these line little change in your code  NSString *emailAddr = @"";
    ABPerson *aPerson = [[ABAddressBookSave sharedAddressBook] me];
    ABMultiValueRef *emails = [aPerson  valueForProperty:kABEmailProperty]; but gives me this error ABPerson undeclared 
    if([emails count] > 0)
        emailAddr = [emails valueAtIndex:0];

Comment: have you added these imports #import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h> and also addressbook.framework in your project?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21934/discussion-between-nscool-and-cyberpawn)